# Using for loop in a method to check for array items in a string - prints 12 lines instead of one

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, methods

New to Java, please be easy on me!

Creating a simple educational app to check for personal pronouns in a thesis sentence. I've almost got it to work, my problem is that the method prints 12 times (instead of checking for 12 pronouns and printing one line).

```
public static void pronoun (String thesis){    

            String [] personalPronouns = {"I","me","you","we","us","our","he","him","she","her","they","them"};

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
                if (thesis.contains(personalPronouns[i])){
                    System.out.println("Oops! Looks like your thesis contains personal pronouns. Remember, avoid using I, you, me, we, us, our, etc. in persuasive essays.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Looks good. Now it's time to start writing! Your essay outline is saved to a txt file called EssayTutorOutline.");
                  }
            }
}
```

If I input "Me has thesis." it returns this:

Looks good...

Looks good...

Looks good...

Looks good...

Looks good...

Looks good...

Oops!...

Looks good...

Looks good...

Looks good...

Looks good...

Looks good...

I'm sure this is obvious to most of you. Been googling all night for an answer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walk through your code, explaining it as you go along, and you'll see the problem.

```
// repeat for each number from 0 to 11
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    // if this string contains the string in personalPronouns[i]
    if (thesis.contains(personalPronouns[i])){
        // print this message
        System.out.println("Oops! Looks like your thesis contains personal pronouns. Remember, avoid using I, you, me, we, us, our, etc. in persuasive essays.");
    } else { // otherwise
        // print this message
        System.out.println("Looks good. Now it's time to start writing! Your essay outline is saved to a txt file called EssayTutorOutline.");
    }
}
```

What you want to do instead is to just figure out if *any* of the pronouns is present. You can do this by setting a `boolean` variable (called a *flag*) that gets changed whenever a personal pronoun matches:

```
boolean personalPronounSeen = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    if (thesis.contains(personalPronouns[i])){
        personalPronounSeen = true;
    }
}
if(personalPronounSeen) {
    // print your message...
}
```

Note that while using a flag is the general solution to the general problem, this still won't do what you want for a number of reasons. In particular, the `contains` method matches a substring, and so you'll be getting lots of false positives, such as any capital I, the words *welcome* and *delicious*, and so on. You also won't match any personal pronouns that have different capitalization.

A more robust approach would be to split `thesis` on whitespace, strip off punctuation from each of the resulting words, add them all to a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and then see if the `Set#contains` any of your pronouns. If you use `TreeSet`, you can tell the collection to ignore case and treat `"We"` and `"we"` the same:

```
Set<String> wordList = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
wordList.add("we");
wordList.contains("We"); // true
```

Finally, take a look at the [enhanced `for` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html); it makes iterating over an array or collection much cleaner and less error-prone. In the case where you really do need to iterate manually, always use `personalPronouns.length` instead of hard-coding the number `12`.

Comment: This is the best logical approach. I like it!

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the time you took to explain this to a newbie like me.

Comment: @user2892609 Programming is largely about learning to think in an ordered manner about exactly how something works. Try to use this sort of approach (follow the steps exactly, and always ask what could go wrong) when you're coding and debugging. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop; inside you have an if statement, where you print one thing if the test is true and a different thing if the test is false.  Why WOULDN'T you expect 12 lines of output?

If your intent is to look at the 12 pronouns, and report at the end if ANY of them were used, you have to wait to print until the loop is done.  I'd suggest a variable that is initialized to mean "none were found", and set it to mean "one was found" if you find any (at which point, you can stop the loop, but don't have too).  Then add your if statement, checking that variable, just AFTER the loop.